# Make selected row bold in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, select, nstableview, bold

I try to make bold row selection style in NSTableView without any highlighting

I switched highlighting off:

```
[myTable setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];
```

However I have some troubles making text bold in selected row. As I suggested, I need to change properties of NSTableView's source:

```
- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSDictionary *boldFont = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]
                                                         forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSDictionary *normalFont = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]
                                                         forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    for(MyClass *obj in tableSourceList)
        obj.name = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                           initWithString:obj.name
                               attributes: normalFont];

    long row = [myTable selectedRow];
    MyClass objectAtSelectedRow = [tableSourceList objectAtIndex: row];
    objectAtSelectedRow.name = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                            initWithString:dr.dreamname
                                attributes: boldFont]; 
    [tableSourceList replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:objectAtSelectedRow];
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no effect.

How to make text in row bold when selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to achieve by altering the table cell to be rendered in the table's delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    // Maybe a test on the table column is recommanded if some cells should not be modified
    NSIndexSet *selection = [aTableView selectedRowIndexes];
    if ([selection containsIndex:rowIndex]) {
        [aCell setFont:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    } else {
        [aCell setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is nearly right, but text become bold only in one column. What did you mean when wrote "test on the table column"?

Comment: Can you add a log to check if the delegate method is called twice per row ?

Comment: I added `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowIndex]);` There's result:`0 0 1 1 2 2` (this fragment repeats several times). There're three rows in the table

Comment: You can assign a column identifier to each table column (in Interface Builder). In the delegate method, you can know which column is rendered by getting the column identifier of the table column object.

Comment: I added `NSLog([aTableColumn identifier]);` - all column names were printed. However bold text appears only in the last column

Comment: I sorted it out. Problems was in some cell's properties, answer is totally correct. Thanks